# How to flatten a tensor product

Tags: list-manipulation, tensors

Say I have a tensor product of four two dimensional spaces
$\Lambda = S\otimes S\otimes S\otimes S$. The basis of $S$ is `CB={{1,0},{0,1}}` . I generate the representation of $\Lambda$ by

```
Lambda=ArrayFlatten[
 ArrayFlatten[
  ArrayFlatten[
   Table[TensorProduct[CB[[i]], CB[[j]], CB[[k]], CB[[m]]], 
   {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}]
  ]
 ]
]
```

The result is

$\Lambda=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Now, I have a problem to generate the corresponding basis vectors, which I thought are given by

```
Flatten[ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[CB[[i]], CB[[j]], CB[[k]], CB[[m]]]]]
```

for $i,j,k,m\in\{1,2\}$. But, e.g.

```
Lambda.Flatten[ArrayFlatten[TensorProduct[CB[[2]], CB[[2]], CB[[1]], CB[[1]]]]]
```

results in the null vector. How to generate the correct basis vectors using `ArrayFlatten[]` or `Flatten[]`?

Answer (score 2):

The basis vectors are

```
CB = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Flatten@*KroneckerProduct @@@ Tuples[CB, 4]

(*    {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}    *)
```

I'm not sure what your matrix $\Lambda$ is: you said it was a vector space, but matrices are rather elements of this vector space, not the space itself.

I've written a book covering this topic: see chapter 2 of [Using Mathematica for Quantum Mechanics: A Student's Manual](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7050).

Comment: My problem is: how do I write e.g. the vector a=TensorProduct[CB[[1]],CB[[2]],CB[[1]],C[[1]]] in the same basis as Lambda, i.e., which of the basis vectors you wrote is a? Thank you for the link, I’ll have a look!

Comment: `a = Flatten@KroneckerProduct[CB[[1]], CB[[2]], CB[[1]], CB[[1]]]` gives the basis vector `{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

Comment: Shoudn't $\Lambda$ be in this case not a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Again, Λ is a vector space, not a matrix.

Comment: It seems my description of the question is misleading: See $\Lambda$ as an operator acting on four spins. The matrix is the representation of this operator.